# How to open safari browser using Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, safari

Can anyone please explain me the below doubt?

How to open google page in safari browser using Selenium WebDriver?

I am using the below code to open the safari browser.

```
WebDriver driver = new SafariDriver();
driver.get("http://www.google.com/");
```

But I am getting "SafariDriver requesting connection at ws://localhost:40921" error message

Can anyone please help me for the above?

Answer (score 2):

You need to install Safari Extensions Developer Certificate in your machine and also install selenium webdriver as an extension in Safari Browser. 
Also there are some stability issues with Safari browser & Selenium combination on Mac 10.9 OS and below.

The stability is much better on Mac Yosemite OSX & Safari 8.0.x combination along with Selenium v2.45.0

Comment: **UPDATE (18th June,2015):** With the latest update of Yosemite 10.10.3 & Safari 8.0.6, the execution on Safari Browsers has become unstable & unreliable.

**Selenium Scripts work best on 10.10.2 , Safari 8.0.3 & Selenium 2.45.0 combination.**

So if OSX prompts you for updates, please **DO NOT** install them if you want to run automation on Safari Browser

Comment: How to install Safari Extensions Developer Certificate?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out these links?

1. http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/SafariDriver
2. http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=3827

Answer (score 0):

Prerequisite: Install Safari on Windows if it is not already installed

1. Go to http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/
2. Scroll down -> Go to the section "SafariDriver" and download "SafariDriver.safariextz"
3. Double click on "SafariDriver.safariextz" (previously downloaded)
4. Safari would open with a pop up containing "Install" button -> Click Install button
5. Now go to Preferences of Safari -> Extensions tab : you would see WebDriver (in my case WebDriver 2.48.0) is installed (Enable WebDriver checkbox is checked))
6. It's now time to instantiate SafariDriver and get the desired URL by using Java. Please find  the code:

   ```
   WebDriver driver = new SafariDriver();<br>
   driver.get("https://www.lynda.com/Ripon-Al-Wasim/8496323-1.html");
   ```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you **don't need to download safaridriver** if you having MacOS High Sierra and later, as its already present by default at

```
   cd /usr/bin
   ls -a
```

Can check here safaridriver is already present
so how to configure this safaridriver in test files

```
    private static final String KEY_SAFARI_WEBDRIVER = "webdriver.safari.driver";
    private static final String SAFARI_WEBDRIVER_PATH = "/usr/bin/safaridriver";
    System.setProperty(KEY_SAFARI_WEBDRIVER, SAFARI_WEBDRIVER_PATH);
    WebDriver driver=new SafariDriver();
```

By default automation testing option is disabled in safari,
can enable it from safari browser

```
Develop -> Allow remote automation
```

reference: https://www.lambdatest.com/blog/selenium-safaridriver-macos/

Answer (score -1):

Try this instead:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.safari.driver","C:/safaridriver.exe")
WebDriver driver = new SafariDriver();
```

Comment: Where to download safaridriver.exe ?

Comment: user4643885: Please provide me the download link of safaridriver.exe